# Using the google maps api for reverse geocoding lat/long from iPhone

Tags: iphone, maps, geocoding, reverse

I am currently using the google maps' reverse geocoding API to convert long/lat received from an iPhone's CoreLocation API into city/state information on a google app engine server.

Would this be considered a violation of the terms? I've done some research and cannot find a direct answer to this question.

Right now, we will be distributing our iPhone app for free.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Google's [Terms of Service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html#section_10_12), you can only use the geocoder in conjunction with a Google Map.

You may not:

> use or display the Content without a
>   corresponding Google map, unless you
>   are explicitly permitted to do so in
>   the Maps APIs Documentation, the
>   Street View API Documentation, or
>   through written permission from Google
>   (for example, you must not use
>   geocodes obtained through the Service
>   except in conjunction with a Google
>   map, but the Street View API
>   Documentation explicitly permits you
>   to display Street View imagery without
>   a corresponding Google map)

Answer (score 0):

Above described terms are not present in revised terms of service. So even Apple co-ordinates should be able to reverse geocode from Google Maps API