# How to find State location from iphone GPS?

Tags: iphone, geocoding, core-location, reverse-geocoding

I'm trying to add to my program that locates the person in GPS but sets a value to 
the State that person is in so example: GPS Locates person from his/her iphone then returns the state they are in so say its California then the state variable gets set to California as a string would someone have an example any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Core Location](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) to find the location and then use [MKReverseGeocoder](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKReverseGeocoder) to get the state from the location.

Comment: Just a warning that MKReverseGeocoder uses Google to do the reverse geocoding -- and as others have posted here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918423/using-the-google-maps-api-for-reverse-geocoding-lat-long-from-iphone/921165#921165), it's against the TOS of the Google Maps API to use the geocoding data unless you're also going to display a corresponding Google Map.  (See section 10.12 of the Terms of Service: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/iphone/terms.html)

Comment: Are there any samples on how to use these methods together?

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is setup a CLLocationManager that will find your current coordinates. With the current coordinates you need to use MKReverseGeoCoder to find your location.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{  
    // this creates the CCLocationManager that will find your current location
    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

// this delegate is called when the app successfully finds your current location
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
    // this creates a MKReverseGeocoder to find a placemark using the found coordinates
    MKReverseGeocoder *geoCoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate];
    geoCoder.delegate = self;
    [geoCoder start];
}

// this delegate method is called if an error occurs in locating your current location
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
 NSLog(@"locationManager:%@ didFailWithError:%@", manager, error);
}
// this delegate is called when the reverseGeocoder finds a placemark
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
{
    MKPlacemark * myPlacemark = placemark;
    // with the placemark you can now retrieve the city name
    NSString *city = [myPlacemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:(NSString*) kABPersonAddressStateKey];
}

// this delegate is called when the reversegeocoder fails to find a placemark
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"reverseGeocoder:%@ didFailWithError:%@", geocoder, error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a few corrections for the above code: 
1. Using kABPersonAddressStateKey will give you the state, not the city 
2. If you have problem with compiling kABPersonAddressStateKey, add the AddressBook framework to your project and include:

```
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
```

in your .m file

Answer (score 0):

Using reverse geocoding is what you need and is straightforward.

Given a class that holds a CLLocation *location property, simply use this code sniper I wrote for one of my project, and you're done.

```
-(void)loadAddress:(void (^)(NSError *error))completion {
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:self.location
                   completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

                       NSString *address = nil;

                       if (error) {
                           self.placemark = nil;
                           self.address = NSLocalizedString(@"Unknown address.",@"");
                       }
                       else {                          
                           CLPlacemark * placeMark = [placemarks firstObject];

                           self.placemark = placeMark;

                           NSDictionary *d = placeMark.addressDictionary;
                           address = [(NSArray*)d[@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
                           self.address = address;
                       }

                       // Call caller
                       if (completion) completion(error);
                   }];

}
```

Note that you will be more interested in getting d[@"State"] rather than d[@"FormattedAddressLines"].
Also note that reverse geocoding requires internet access (it's implemented as a Web service) and is subject to volume limitation. Most likely, you shouldn't exceed more than a couple of calls per minute. If you exceed the quota set by Apple, you'll receive an error.

For your convenience, here are the KV stored by the placeMark.addressDictionary proprerty:

```
{
    City = Millbrae;
    Country = "Etats-Unis";
    CountryCode = US;
    FormattedAddressLines =     (
        "I-280 N",
        "Half Moon Bay, CA  94019",
        "Etats-Unis"
    );
    Name = "I-280 N";
    State = CA;
    Street = "I-280 N";
    SubAdministrativeArea = "San Mat\U00e9o";
    SubLocality = "Bay Area";
    Thoroughfare = "I-280 N";
    ZIP = 94019;
}
```