# Reverse geocode without using MKReverseGeocoder

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, geolocation, core-location

I'm trying to detect current user address using MKReverseGeocoder passing coordinates obtained via CLLocation class. Reading [MKReverseGeocoder Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) I noticed that

> The Google terms of service require that the reverse geocoding service be used in conjunction with a Google map; take this into account when designing your application's user interface.

so I'm wondering if (and eventually how) can I reverse geocode user current location on iPhone OS SDK 3.1.3.
I thought using Google Maps API but the EULA has the same obligation.
Yahoo Maps API is even worse and Microsoft one aren't free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.geonames.org/ is another free alternative

Answer (score 1):

Well if the EULA of Google has the obligation and you are not following it ( similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918423/using-the-google-maps-api-for-reverse-geocoding-lat-long-from-iphone)), then of course you **can't** do it.

Still I would advice you to find some alternatives, what about [this](http://geocoder.ca/?api=1), it's free and doesn't look bad at all.

Answer (score 0):

a question on geonames:
for retrieving city i must pass north,south,eas,west; there's a way to pass only lat & long for retrieve city? I canno't find method to do...

Comment: You can try http://ws.geonames.org/extendedFindNearby?lat=47.3&lng=9 and parse the response

Comment: yes, i've see that method but, if i inser the coordinate of my city (milan, italy) i retrieve only a suburbe of milan... Earth 0.0 0.0 6295630 L AREA Europe 48.6909603909255 9.140625 6255148 L CONT Italy 42.8333333 12.8333333 3175395 IT Italy A PCLI Lombardy 45.6666667 9.5 3174618 IT Italy A ADM1 Fiera Campionaria 45.4772856285137 9.1556453704834 6693841 IT Italy P PPLX  -> Fiera campionaria that's is a "zone" of milan. Any ideas?